# Selecting nested elements of checked radio button with CSS only

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to use CSS to select some elements base on `radio` button state.

What I would like to do is if a certain `radio` button is checked I want to go down a couple levels and `unhide` an overlay so that the user can interact with the disabled `radio` buttons.

I know you can use sibling selectors like `~` and `>` to select siblings of the current `div`, but how would I select a parent element of a `checked` radio button and then traverse down the DOM to find my desired selector?

I can easily do this with JS but I would prefer CSS if it is possible.

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLXgGe)

You can see that I have four `radio` buttons. Two of which are indented slightly.

What I would like to accomplish is if someone selects the **Testing2** `radio` I want the `.overlay` that contains the `opacity` to be set to `display: none`.

I need to also maintain the same structure without reorganizing the HTML.

Using sibling selectors are relatively new to me so I am probably not using them correctly in this case.

I have tried:

```
 #radio-1:checked ~ .overlay {
      display: none;
    }

    #radio-1:checked > .radio-bump > .radio-group-2 ~ .overlay {
      display: none;
    }
```

Here is my code:

```css
.overlay {
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.radio-group-2 {
  position: relative;
}
.radio-bump {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#radio-1:checked ~ .overlay {
  display: none;
}
#radio-1:checked > .radio-bump > .radio-group-2 ~ .overlay {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="shipping-container">
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="radio" name="radio-group-1">
      <label for="radio">Testing1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-1">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="radio-group-1">
      <label for="radio-1">Testing2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-bump">
      <div class="radio-group-2">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="radios">
          <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radio-group-2">
          <label for="radio-2">Testing3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radios">
          <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="radio-group-2">
          <label for="radio-3">Testing4</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only possible (with pure CSS) if you remove the containers from each radio/label. Also, you should consider using pointer-events instead of an overlay:

```css
label:after { content: ""; display: block;}

.radio-group-2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  opacity: .7;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input:checked + label + .radio-group-2 {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="r-1" name="radio-group-1"><label for="r-1">Testing 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="r-2" name="radio-group-1"><label for="r-2">Testing 2</label>
<div class="radio-group-2">
  <input type="radio" id="r-3" name="radio-group-2"><label for="r-3">Testing 3</label>
  <input type="radio" id="r-4" name="radio-group-2"><label for="r-4">Testing 4</label>
</div>
```

Note the use of the adjacent sibling selector.

Comment: Also consider `input:not(:checked) + label + .radio-group-2 { opacity: .7; pointer-events: none;}`

Comment: This is the first time I have heard of `pointer-events`. We did not learn about them in my HTML5/CSS3 course. My research just now showed that they are involved in SVG. At the risk of sounding newb, how does that apply here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Given your condition

> I need to also maintain the same structure without reorganizing the
>   HTML.

Then the answer to your question, if this is possible to this with CSS only is **NO**, because CSS has no Parent selector,  if you could reorganize your HTML, then CSS would be capable of achieving this, by using either the adjacent selector `+` or the sibling selector `~`

You have more info on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) regards to parent selector in css

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you're asking for here cannot be achieved in pure CSS using your current HTML tree. `#radio1` simply cannot be in the same selector as `.radio-bump`.

You will need to put the radio button element higher up the DOM tree in order to achieve this.

What you can do to make it look the way you want is to put the radio button higher in the tree, but keep the label where it is. Then make the radio button element `display:none` and add a `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element to the label styled to look like a radio button.

A similar technique is also used for creating pure CSS tabs.